# Datetime datapicker with mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to use the jQuery UI datetime picker for this project. With a shared partial view that look like this, and it is not working.
I have a partial view in my shared folder, name `DateTime`

```
@model System.DateTime?
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue,
      new
      {
          data_datepicker = true
      });
```

It should effect this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Until ,new{@class="date"})
```

I have also tried scripting but no results.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you mark your Model variable with UIHint.

```
[DisplayName("Number of Hours")] 
[UIHint("HoursOfTheDay")] 
public Decimal NumberOfHours { get; set; }
```

Check out this article:
http://www.devcurry.com/2013/04/custom-templates-in-aspnet-mvc.html

Comment: it is :  public DateTime Until { get; set; } do I need a UIHint?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your model is marked up as being `DateTime` and not the nullable type `DateTime?`.

Change your model property to this and it should pick it up:

```
 public DateTime? Until { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you model property to this

```
public DateTime Until { get; set; }
```

and `view`

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Until, new { @class = "date" })
```

No need to use `Javascript` for `DateTimePicker`. see this example http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc-part-1

Comment: [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime Until { get; set; },    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Until, new { @class ="date"})  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("date").datepicker(
                { formatDate: 'dd-mm-yy' }
            );
        });
    </script> also  with the script it's still the same